# Como faço pra jogar um valor de um input, sem submeter um form ou botão

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, aplicação-web

Olá, queria pegar o valor do input `"codigo_cat"` e jogar na variável  `$id_categoria` que está em baixo no código **PHP**, pra conseguir rodar o select usando esta variável como parâmetro.
Por método *GET* E *POST* eu conseguiria fazer, o problema é que eu não estou submetendo nenhum form ou botão, para que um método seja usado.

Tem como fazer isso? Se alguém souber me ajude. Estou a 2 dias tentando fazer isso! Obrigado.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="codigo">Código</label>
            <input name="codigo" id="codigo_cat" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="0" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php 
            $id_categoria = (QUERO O VALOR DO INPUT AQUI);

            $query = "SELECT ativo AS ativo_status FROM categoria WHERE idCategoria = '$id_categoria'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if ($row['ativo_status'] == 'S') {
        ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" checked>
        <?php
            } else {
        ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo">
        <?php
            }
        ?>

        <label for="ativo">Ativo</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uma dúvida que eu fiquei, como você obtêm o valor do campo id=codigo_cat, ele é reandonly deve ser preenchido por alguém, resta saber se é pelo javascript ou pelo php

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível fazer dessa forma. O interpretador do PHP vai ser executado no momento da requisição do navegador. Você precisa entender que existem dois atores: servidor e cliente. O servidor é responsável por processar o PHP e envia para o cliente (navegador) o resultado do código PHP já processado. O que você tá querendo fazer é processar código PHP no lado do navegador e isso não é possível, para isso existe javascript.

Isso que você tá querendo só pode ser obtido através de javascript, ou utilizando Ajax ou usando somente javascript. Porém aconselho estudar mais sobre como o PHP funciona e como as requisições a um servidor web ocorre, além de entender melhor o protocolo http e depois Javascript e por fim entender como funciona o Ajax.

Comment: Via javascript(jquery) voce tem a funcao on('change' que fica esperando modificacoes e on('blur' que fica esperando voce mudar o cursor para outro objeto. Dentro dessas funcoes voce pode pegar o valor de qqr campo. E posteriormente exibir em outro lugar, uma variavel ou ate mesmo outro campo.

Comment: Entendi, vou procurar estudar mais sobre o assunto. Sou esse é meu primeiro projeto profissional. Começei programar web agora. Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 2):

O Francisco tem rezão o que você deseja fazer do modo que esta tentando fazer não tem como funcionar.
Vai ter que dar uma olhada em `$ajax` do jQuery e incluir ele em sua página.

Ficaria algo assim usando `.load` que é mais simples:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="codigo">Código</label>
            <input name="codigo" id="codigo_cat" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="0" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="retorno"> <!--vai ter que dar um id aqui -->
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("$codigo-cat").change(function(){
        var id_categoria = $(this).val();
        $("#retorno").load("consulta.php", {"id_categoria": id_categoria});
    });
</script>
```

PHP (consulta.php):

```
<?php 
    $id_categoria = $_POST['id_categoria'];
    $query = "SELECT ativo AS ativo_status FROM categoria WHERE idCategoria = '$id_categoria'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['ativo_status'] == 'S') {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" checked>';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo">';
    }
?>
```

Assim sempre que houver mudanças no id_categoria a consulta será chamada de forma assíncrona retornando o input dado pelo echo do php.

Comment: Dei o Up no Fransisco, mas ambas as respostas são melhores juntas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, vou testar o código acima e melhor de tudo, conseguir entede-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Francisco Eduardo esta certo.
Aqui tens um simples exemplo para Ajax

### HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return OnSubmitData(this)">
    <input type="text" name="teste">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function OnSubmitData(e)
{    
    let oForm = document.forms[e.id];
    // Loop dos campos do formulario
    for(var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++)
    {
        let elemForm = oForm.elements[i];
        // Ele aqui ignora o botao submit
        if( elemForm.getAttribute("type") == "submit" ) continue;
        // Mostra os resultados dos campos do formulario
        console.log(elemForm.name + ": " + elemForm.value );
    }
    // Cancela acao 'OnSubmit' de envio do formulario
    return false;
}
```

Funcao para enviar os dados

```
function SendDataToServer(_data)
{
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          //
          console.log("Texto recebido do servidor -> " + this.responseText);
      }
  };
  // Aqui envia os dados 
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/TeuFicheiro.php?data="+_data, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Espero que ajude em alguma coisa